# Efficient algorithm for finding closest point for rotated and scaled $\mathbb{Z}_n$ lattice

Tags: lattice, integer-lattice

Suppose we have a $\mathbb{Z}_n$ lattice generated by the identity matrix $I_n$. Here I would like to consider a rotated and scaled $\mathbb{Z}_n$ lattice $\Lambda$ with the generator matrix $M=I_n*O*Z$ ($*$ is matrix multiplication and notice the order of multiplication) where O is an orthogonal matrix that rotates the basis vectors and $Z$ is a generic diagonal matrix that scales the **unrotated** basis vectors. Here the row vectors of $M$ are the basis vectors of $\Lambda$. My question is how to efficiently find the closest lattice point in $\Lambda$ for a given point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

A few notes

1. Considered separately, the closest lattice point for lattices $M_1=I_n*O$ and $M_2=I_n*Z$ are fairly easy to find as one simply need to find the closest point for $O^{-1}x$ and $Z^{-1}x$ respectively. This is the case because the basis vectors in $M_{1,2}$ are orthogonal to each other.
2. This is however not the case for $M=I_n*O*Z$ and the basis vectors are generally not orthogonal to each other (if we were to scale the basis vectors first followed by rotation, the resulting set of basis vectors would be still orthogonal)
3. We have algorithms to find closest lattice point for general lattice, see [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.2817&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for one example. But these algorithms often scales exponentially with the lattice size n and does not make use of the structure of the lattice. I would like to know if it is possible to exploit the structure of $\Lambda$ (rotated and scaled from $\mathbb{Z}_n$) to find the closest point more efficiently.

Thanks for the help!